# Как обеспечить коэффициент вероятности?

Tags: теория-вероятностей, c++11, c++

Скажем есть некая программа, симулирующая подброс монетки.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы в 95 случаях подброса монетки из ста выпадал орел, а не решка.
Как можно этого добиться?

Comment: а почему в метках указан С++ 11? Думаете, эту архисложную задачу можно решить только с привлечением средств последнего стандарта С++?

Comment: Конечно, именно так

Comment: Страуструп, наверное, подавился бы, узнав, об этом

Comment: Что ж, жаль его

Comment: Себя пожалейте, он-то с С++, думаю, знаком неплохо и в Вашей жалости вряд ли нуждается

Comment: А чего мне себя жалеть?

Comment: А что именно вам надо: чтобы _шансы_ на выпадение орла были 95 из 100 (то есть, вероятность), или чтобы из 100 попыток подряд всегда _ровно_ 95 раз выпадал орёл?

Comment: @VladD, шансы. Точнее, чтобы процент выпадения орла по отношению к решке стремился к отметке в 95 процентов

Comment: @SoloMio: тогда пользуйтесь не резервуаром, а rand.

Comment: @SoloMio: ещё большие потери владельцы казино понесут, если ваш алгоритм будет предсказуемым, т.е., не случайным. Надо объяснять почему?

Comment: @VladD -  для начала нарисуйте распределение p(орёл) = 0.95, p(решка) = 0.5 :).

При достаточно большом кол-ве применения алгоритма будет предоставлять такую же случайность, как и rand (можно доказать, что эта случайность будет такая же как у rand или немного хуже).

>> ещё большие потери владельцы казино понесут, если ваш алгоритм будет предсказуемым

то, что это для казино, сильно меняет дело. В этом случае rand также предсказуем. Для этого используют аппаратные генераторы. В некоторых "интернет покеррумах" даже используют настоящих людей, которые перетасовывают карты.

Comment: @SoloMio, тут такой спор о случайно-не-случайно пошел...

Вы уточните, какой процесс моделируется. Тасуется колода (если много игр, то одна и та же) или бросаются монеты?

Comment: @VladD, нет, не нужно. Прекрасно понимаю. @KoVadim Спасибо за идею, почитаю насчет аппаратных генераторов.  
@avp, Как бы так объяснить. Это автомат, по типу однорукого бандита. Составляется матрица 5 x 5 из случайных значений из диапазона [1..4], на основе этой матрицы определяются выиграшные комбинации. Алгоритм генерации случайных матриц должен обеспечивать соотношение выигрышей к проигрышам примерно как 94 ко 100. Т.е. в принципе да, тасуется как бы колода, только вместо колоды у нас матрица значений, забитая символами.

Comment: Ну, если колода, то используйте ответ @KoVadim.

Comment: @KoVadim: задал [вопрос на маткоде](http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/14156/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

rand - это хорошее решение и на больших объемах данных он даст достаточно равномерное распределение. Но на не очень больших будет небольшой разброс (несколько процентов). Если же нужна 100% гарантия, что будет правильная вероятность, тогда нужно использовать другой подход. Смотрите мой пример, если Ваш компилятор не поддерживает последний стандарт, то просто посмотрите, как реализована [shuffle](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/?kw=shuffle).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   vector<int> a(100); // массив на 100 бросков

   fill_n(a.begin(), 95, 1); // 1 - это орлы
   fill_n(a.begin() + 95, 5, 0); // 0 - это решки

   // теперь магия. получаем сид и перемешиваем массив   
   unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();   
   shuffle(a.begin(), a.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));

   // делаем подсчет
   int orel = count_if (a.begin(), a.end(), [](int i){return (i==1);} );
   int reshka = count_if (a.begin(), a.end(), [](int i){return (i==0);} );
   // выведем соотношение
   cout << "орлов/решек " << orel << "/" << reshka << endl;

   // выведем набор
   for_each (a.begin(), a.end(), [](int i) {cout << i << " ";});
   cout << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно то что и нужно было

Comment: <мелкие_придирки>вероятность как раз правильная в случае простого rand. вероятность того, что из 100 бросков выпадет ровно 95 орлов равна в точности `C^5_100/2^100 = 75287520 / 1267650600228229401496703205376 ~= 6*10^{-23}`</мелкие_придирки>

Comment: а оно нам нужно? задача то была не в этом.

Comment: @KoVadim: Да, согласен, вычисления не верны, т.к. они отталкиваются от равных вероятностей выпадения орла и решки, чего априори нет. Но: ваша последовательность не случайна! Например, если сначала выпало 5 решек подряд, гарантированно дальше выпадет 95 орлов, что в случае монеты не так: вероятность выпадения орла не имеет права зависеть от предыдущих результатов.

Comment: Ваши рассуждения не имеют ничего общего с задачей.

Comment: @KoVadim: может быть, может быть, вопрос интерпретации. Я специально переспросил ТС в комментариях, нужно ли ему точное значение к-ва выпадений, или шансы единичного выпадения. Насколько я понял его ответ, ему нужна случайная последовательность с вероятностью орла 0.95. Заметьте, что вашему пониманию (случайность не нужна) соответствует и более простое решение: (1) на первых 5 запросов вернуть решку, (2) на следующие 95 запросов вернуть орла, (3) повторять циклически. Перемешивание в соответствии с вашим пониманием не нужно.

Comment: >> Заметьте, что вашему пониманию (случайность не нужна) соответствует и более простое решение:

>> Перемешивание в соответствии с вашим пониманием не нужно.

я этого не говорил.

Comment: @KoVadim: не говорили, но, как мне кажется, это выплывает из вашей трактовки задачи: если не обязательно, чтобы последовательность была случайной (а мой комментарий говорил именно об этом: ваша последовательность не случайна, значит вы считаете, что случайность не нужна), то подойдёт и решение без перемешивания.

Comment: последовательность, которую генерит мой код настолько случайна, насколько случаен rand.  Все остальные трактовки Вы придумали.

Comment: это программа для казино, однорукий бандит. нужно чтобы соотношение выигрышей к проигрышам равнялось примерно такому соотношению.

Answer (score 6):

Генерируй случайное число. От одного до ста. Потом пишешь: если число меньше 95, тогда орёл, иначе решка. Вот и будет вероятность 0,95

Comment: это если распределение равномерное, если же нет, то у нас орел будет в куда меньшем количестве чем нужно.

Comment: случайное число и подразумевает, что любое число выпадет с одинаковой вероятностью.

Comment: нужна гарантия

Comment: мамой клянусъ!

Comment: Ха-ха, как смешно

Comment: >Ха-ха, как смешно

любезнейший, а откуда такая дуболомная серьезность? Вам дали очевиднейший ответ на более чем элементарный вопрос, а вы нос воротите. Хоть бы спасибо сказали ответившим. Не нравится алгоритм генерации случайных числел в С++? Напишите свой с блэкджеком и барышнями, вероятно, он будет куда как лучше тех, что уже реализованы в языке

Comment: Спасибо-то спасибо, но зачем при даче ответа язвить и что-то там еще делать? Ну ответили бы просто: "функция Rand() возвращает число в соответствии с равномерным законом распределения вероятности", и никаких проблем. К чему этот сарказм, "мамой клянусь"? Мне эта информация нужна для написания тестового задания, это приложение для казино. И если в итоге распределение будет не равномерным, а экспоненциальным к примеру, кто-то потеряет много денег. Не сложно догадаться кому будет плохо после этого.

Comment: Или мне кажется.. или что-то другое смущает, но генератор случайных чисел, типа rand(), т.е. без параметров, дающих готовую выборку не даст "строгой гарантии"?!

Answer (score 4):

Давайте вспоминать математику школьного курса за 5 класс :) Тема: "правильные дроби".

```
95 из 100( вероятность выпадения орла --- 95/100 ) => 95/100 = 19/20 => вам нужно подбирать число в диапазоне от 1 до 20 :

srand(time(NULL));  
int res = rand()%20+1;
cout<<res<<endl;
if(res==20) cout<<"Решка!"; else cout<<"Орел!";
cout<<endl;
```

Comment: так по сути, что я и предложил. естественно, что оптимальнее будет сократить.

Comment: Не оптимальнее - вернее. При генерации чисел от 1 до 100 вероятность генерации чисел от 95 до 100 может быть несколько меньше. Обусловлено это может быть тем, что процессор генерирует псевдослучайные числа в соответствии с заданным "зерном". Поправьте кто-нибудь, если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: позапускайте такой код и поудивляйтесь

    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
       const int range = 10000;
       int q = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
          int t = rand() % 100;
          if (t >= 95)
            q++;
       }
       cout << q*100.0/range << endl;
       return 0;
    }

Только при 100000-1000000 попыток, процент стает правильным.

Comment: @KoVadim: по такой логике, для вероятности 0.5 надо, чтобы всегда попеременно генерировался орёл и решка?

Comment: @VladD В данном случае гарантируется, что на каком-то заведомо известном количестве попыток, можно сказать, сколько выпадет орлов и решек. Поэтому, не обязательно, что бы выпадало попеременно при вероятности 0.5. Но к примеру при 40 попытках точно выпадет 20 орлов.

@Hancock логично, что будет выпадать 50, 33 и так далее. Если пойдете дальше, то вероятность будет равна приблизительно `100 / k`. Догадаетесь почему?:)

Comment: @KoVadim: Не совсем. Если вероятность 1/2, ваш резервуар будет размером в 2, верно? Хуже того, последовательность с резервуаром _не случайна_: вы _всегда_ можете предсказать, каким будет последний результат в резервуаре, чего не может быть с честной монетой. Для настоящей монеты броски независимы (испытания Бернулли), в частности, есть ненулевая вероятность выпадения миллиарда орлов подряд. В случае с резервуаром этого нету.

Comment: в случае 1/2 резервуар может быть равен двум, но не обязательно. 

>> последовательность с резервуаром не случайна: вы всегда можете предсказать, каким будет последний результат в резервуаре
логично. Но это будет известно только тогда, когда будут проанализированы все предыдущие элементы.

Приведу контрпример. Представьте себе колоду карт. Если ее перетасовать, то карты там будут в случайном порядке, но после того, как все, кроме последней будут извлечены, всегда можно предсказать последнюю карту. Но от этого она менее случайной не станет.

Это как с котом Шрёдингера.

Comment: @KoVadim: последняя карта в колоде, конечно _не_ случайна, вы же её точно знаете. Случайна лишь вся _перестановка_ карт. Хуже того, каждая вытянутая карта даёт информацию об оставшихся картах, профессиональные игроки в покер это прекрасно понимают.

---
А что мешает выбрать резервуар размером в 2? Что в тексте вопроса, по вашему мнению, это запрещает?

Comment: Она не случайна, если все предыдущие карты известны. Но если просто взять "последнюю карту", то она ещё как случайна.

>> А что мешает выбрать резервуар размером в 2?  Что в тексте вопроса, по вашему мнению, это запрещает?

Очень сложно обеспечить в этом случае вероятность 0.95.

Но если бы у человека стояла задача получить два случайных броска, при этом должна быть одна решка и один орел, тогда резервуар 2 самое оно.

Размер резервуара подбирается в соответствии с задачей. Возможно автору нужен резервуар в 10000.

Comment: @KoVadim:

> два случайных броска, при этом должна быть одна решка и один орел

В такой формулировке это невозможно, потому что для действительно случайных бросков результат второго броска _не зависит_ от результата первого! Т. обр. вы никак не можете гарантировать к-во выпадений для случайных бросков.

То, о чём вы говорите, это случайное расположение `n` орлов и `m` решек, для неё _последовательность_ бросков не случайна по упомянутым причинам.

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно гарантировано 95% орел, то нужно делать список например из 100 (нужно точно знать количество подбросов), 5 любых (допустим первых) делать true, остальные false, а потом выдёргивать рандомно их поодному из списка, чтоб они не повторялись, получится, что к концу списка отношение стопро будет 95/5

Answer (score 3):

Тема конечно старая, но никто так и предложил с++11 way. Поэтому на правах просвящения народных масс:

```
// bernoulli_distribution
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
  const int nrolls=10000;

  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::bernoulli_distribution distribution(0.95);

  int count=0;  // count number of trues

  for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i) if (distribution(generator)) ++count;

  std::cout << "bernoulli_distribution (0.95) x 10000:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "true:  " << count << std::endl;
  std::cout << "false: " << nrolls-count << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

[Попробовать на ideone](http://ideone.com/OMalEr)